# text editor for jquery ,dojo,mootools

Tags: jquery, dojo, mootools, text-editor

I need a text editor that supports cross platform JavaScript languages such as jQuery or MooTools.

I do not mean a rich text editor. I'm looking for an "intellisense" text editor
to develop in those languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think IntelliJ is as good an editor for JavaScript as there is.  They parse everything into an abstract syntax tree, so the tool can be very smart about knowing what you need to do.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for an IDE? If so [Aptana or Eclipse+Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) are reasonable choices - good javascript support as well as jquery and mootools specific support. Bit of a resource hog, but not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

[dojox.highlight](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/highlight) has code to do the parsing and such.  I think a couple of people have written text editors based on this or similar technologies, a few were based on RTE which turned out not to perform well.

You may want to look at EditArea, which I don't think is based on any of these toolkits.  You might also look at Bespin, which is very sophisticated but a larger piece of code built on SproutCore.